# Converting a Sorted Map from Java to an sorted object readable in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, json, sorting

I have a ConcurrentSkipListMap which stores sorted data based on the timestamp since epoch. Now using Servlets I want to return this data to the browser. But, when I convert the Java map into JSON the order is lost(I know JSON doesn't maintain it). I have also tried to return a string to the user which I create while iterating the map

```
returnString = "{";
for (Map.Entry<Long, String> entry : mapname.entrySet()) {
    returnString += "\"" + String.valueOf(entry.getKey()) + "\":" + "\"" + entry.getValue() + "\",";
}
returnString += "}";
```

This String with escape sequences works untill my `getValue()` is a String. If it turns out to be a JSON Object, Javascript is unable to parse the entire object because the escape sequences are missing for that value.

I want to return to the browser a format which is easily readable in JavaScript and which will not require me to sort in JavaScript as my Map in Java is already sorted.
Is this possible? How?

PS: I may be missing something obvious because I've had my head into this for hours.

Comment: in addition to the GSON recommendations below, consider using Jackson as well.  No point re-inventing the wheel and writing your own JSON processing unless you have a special use case.

Comment: If you want to convey order in JSON you'll have to use an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library. It will help you

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.setPrettyPrinting();
        builder.serializeNulls();
        Gson  gsonExt = builder.create();
        String serialize = gsonExt.toJson(mapname);
```

Comment: Please don't post answers that are nothing but a library recommendation. Even if you suggest a library - explain why, and include relevant code.

Comment: Thanks, much better. If you could explain why using the Gson library is better than serializing it himself (it's easier, less mistakes, and so on) that'd be even better.